# SOQL returning incorrect value

Tags: soql, formula-field, user

This is throwing me for a loop. I have a custom field on user, Backend_User__c. The formula is pretty simple:

```
IF(
 OR( Profile.Name = "API Only",
     Profile.Name = "Boldchat API Only",
     Profile.Name = "Business Intelligence (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "Business Office (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "Chat Representative (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "Compliance (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "GUAppDev API Only",
     Profile.Name = "IT (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "IT - App Dev",
     Profile.Name = "Marketing (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "Marketing User",
     Profile.Name = "Read Only All Records",
     Profile.Name = "Registrar (Custom)",
     Profile.Name = "System Administrator",
     Profile.Name = "System Administrator (Clone)",
     Profile.Name = "Read Only",
     Profile.Name = "Partner Community User"
   ),
TRUE,
FALSE
)
```

This appears to be showing correctly when I look at the user records. However, when I run SOQL against it, the values are not correct. For example:
`SELECT Name, Id, Profile.Name, Username, Alias, Bogus_User__c, IsActive, Backend_User__c FROM User` returns false for a System Administrator. I go to the user record, and the field is checked. As it should be.

What is causing this?

Comment: Can u verify field level security?

Comment: I can. I have read permission granted to every user. Also, it *IS* returning a value, False!

Comment: You can *always* replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with `condition`. It's already the exact same boolean value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000181gKQAQ) that can occur. It goes way back to the days when the standard profiles were named PTX, where X was a number. They still occasionally end up showing up in odd places, and you've found one of them.

As a matter of practicality, you don't need an "if" statement here, since your intent is to return true/false. You can also optimize this with a CASE statement. Here's the resulting formula:

```
1 = CASE(
    Profile.Name,
    "API Only", 1, 
    "Boldchat API Only", 1,
    "Business Intelligence (Custom)", 1,
    "Business Office (Custom)", 1,
    "Chat Representative (Custom)", 1,
    "Compliance (Custom)", 1,
    "GUAppDev API Only", 1,
    "IT (Custom)", 1,
    "IT - App Dev", 1,
    "Marketing (Custom)", 1,
    "Marketing User", 1, "PT5", 1,
    "Read Only All Records", 1,
    "Registrar (Custom)", 1,
    "System Administrator", 1, "PT1", 1,
    "System Administrator (Clone)", 1,
    "Read Only", 1, "PT3", 1,
    "Partner Community User" 1,
    0
)
```

This formula presumes that the bug will eventually be fixed, so includes the PTX variants for standard profile names that are affected. The full list is mentioned in [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hmm interesting - one for the ancient bug that I've never heard of and two for your interesting logic... is it true that the system auto evaluates 1=0 as False? (it is false, of course, but the auto evaluation is unexpected)

Comment: This looks great and I made the changes you suggest, but the problem still persists. Specifically for the system admin, which is mapped to PT1, correct? Would I be better suited to just use the IDs of the profile? And since this is a sandbox, would the profile IDs translate into Production (provided they were refreshed from production)?

Comment: @CasparHarmer Yes, it's a workaround since CASE cannot return true/false directly. It's often used as a shortcut when you want to compare one field to many values. All of the Boolean operators return a true/false result you can use directly.

Comment: @Chance I would consider that a last resort, but should be acceptable if you can't find any other way. I would suggest experimenting with a formula that just returns Profile.Name directly to see what the results are, then use those values.

Comment: OK, so I have done everything I can and the problem still persists. Does it matter that the checkbox is accurately showing checked? If the checkbox is showing checked, why would the SOQL fail on that?

Comment: @Chance If the checkbox is checked, the SOQL should find it, especially since you also queried Profile.Name. You may need to contact Support if the problem persists. I'm not sure there's much more we can do for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox you were correct. Even support is escalating this problem. Thank you for your help!